# What could be the list of top 4 superpowers of Earth by 2050, according to current state?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, near-future, futurology

I design an amateur (indie) sci-fi video game and wondering about which of current states or federations (like European Union) could be the top 4 superpowers by, say 2050. I care about technology and the economy as well because it will be some kind of strategy game and yes, I need 4, not 3, and not 5 factions by design decision.

I think the USA, EU, China, India, Russia could be possible choices, but as I know the population of Africa will be a very huge percent of the Earth's population by 2050 (but I don't think to Africa will be united). Other possibilities also imaginable, but I could be happy if anybody could write an argument with reasonable facts to this question.

Comment: Any country that would not be exploited by the main players you mentioned. Because those countries would be nuked.

Comment: 1 important factor to note is actually the EU could crumble in the next 30 years, its unlikely i admit, but i Britain manage to successfully exit without screwing it up badly as they currently are, then it will prove that the EU is not as important as it is seen to be, and other states may look to exit as well, its part of the reason why the EU is giving Britain such a hard deal

Comment: It could but as you admit as well, it is unlikely. GB is a slightly different story I think because of its special history and different culture maybe because of the island effect, maybe for another reason(s). In addition, the economy of GB has had an advantage with EU-membership (undoubtful, London is a financial center), but GB was always more independent in economical and political traits than a continental member of EU.

Comment: @BenceLászló If you want to reply to comment, as a matter of protocol you add "@" to their user name in form at the beginning of this comment. This only works for one user per comment.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, BenceLaszlo, since the future is unknowable we have to rely on probabilities the nations you mention are the most likely candidates for being the principal superpowers in 2050. You have a window of opportunity to nominate whatever four you prefer.

Comment: Thank you @a4android . I will use the '@' mark to mention.

Comment: By what criteria do you rank them? I get tech and economy, but those are broad, abstract and not really measurable things. You need some key figures to really decide which nation is more likely 4th and which is 5th. Which are the top 4 right now according to those criteria?

Comment: What in blazes does this have to do with Worldbuilding ?

Comment: @Raditz_35 let's say, GDP for the economy, and spaceships/rockets or such advanced technologies for the science.

Comment: @StephenG it will be fractions on a world of a video game. I like to choose from real-world civilizations what likely be a significant power in the near future.

Comment: Additional information is best included via edit of the original post. I can accept the GDP, but your tech criterium is binary, you have it or you don't, and I can think of more than 4 entities that already have a space program. Also you have not provided a way to weigh them against each other + compare them with GDP. If a has a better spaceship (whatever that means) than b but b has more GDP, who wins? Also I don't think space flight in general is at all desirable in 50 years and a good indicator for tech, but that's purely subjective. And you should research the top 4 right now and why

Comment: Ps: I want to point out that my a vs b is not purely theoretical and pedantic. Russia beats any other country when it comes to space flight, but the GDP is an actual issue

Comment: This is just an opinion based question.  Scenario - the tiny country of Wibblestonia, formed after the breakup of the UK post Brexit, develops a doomsday device.  They become, de facto, a world power because they can't be safely attacked and can't be safely ignored, especially with their leader BorisJ whose unstable mental state is a problem.  Literally *any* country or group of countries cold become a superpower.

Comment: @StephenG to be honest, it's very unlikely to born a new country from the ashes of UK. Probability not equals opinion.

Comment: @Raditz_35 For game design it would be great to have fractions with different advantages and disadvantages as you wrote Russia's traits. It seems that science would be one of the most difficult questions. What is in your mind?  Is there any universal measurement for scientific advancement?

Comment: No but you could be satisfied with a measurement with issues. I would solve the issue differently btw: pick them to be inclusive and diverse. A NATO-style faction for usa/europe/Australia, a Russia faction, an African alliance and a China thingy, perhaps one with a loose alliance with India/Japan/korea. Doesnt matter if they are the top 4 in something you can't measure as is evident. Choose what is most interesting

Comment: @Raditz_35 I will think about it, thank you for the advice. My idea was to make it realistic, but it seems that it is harder than I thought before.

Comment: You can hand-wave almost any reasonable scenario you want.  Or even unreasonable: who in i969 would have predicted the collapse of Communism and the breakup of the USSR?  So with equal logic, you could have a charismatic leader uniting much of Africa, ISIS taking over the Muslim world, the western US forming its own country...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two that you haven't mentioned in your potential list are the United Kingdom and Japan.

Japan currently holds the 3rd position in terms of economic rankings (although this precludes the EU) and the other advantage they have over other countries for the future is that they are currently still investing heavily in scientific research. There are some fields of physics in which the only research jobs in the world are located in Japan. The downside is that at present they have a declining population (actually negative population growth) meaning that their numbers may not support their economic goals for the future at some point (although this is doubtful to manifest as a real issue in 32 years).

The UK is reasonably high on the list and the loss of its economy to the EU will be a blow in some regards. It is completely dwarfed by the combined economies of the EU of course, but it currently sits at 5th in economic rankings but has been dropping. It is less likely to be a power going forward unless it reverses this trend, but it may well do so in the future. Its success was largely based on military technology sales, but the USA has dwarfed its capability in that regard for some time and it is looking for other areas of development now. I don't know enough about how this search is going, but if it finds a good niche, then you might just find it on the rise again. The people of the UK are generally unafraid of hard work to achieve such goals.

**Wildcard Bonus**
Given the ever increasing population size, some commodities that we take for granted now may well become even more important than technical wares into the future. The obvious ones here are food and energy. If food becomes the 'new oil' insofar as it becomes the most important commodity for global trade, then one country that's not currently in the race may well rise;

Australia.

Hear me out on this one; Australia exports a lot of minerals, yes, but it also exports a lot of food. It has a far greater capacity to grow food than it has to consume it and this could easily make it a superpower in the future if the need for food increases. Additionally, Australia is more or less the 'Saudi Arabia' of uranium, with around 30% of the world's reserves. If nuclear power for all those people suddenly becomes the norm, then Australia's rise as an economic superpower is assured. It's already investing in higher learning, with tertiary education now being its third highest export. All we'd need now is a solid research program and we're set...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I will suggest my team to increase the number of fractions because you inspired me with such good ideas. I knew before that Australia is rich in natural resources and well-being, but what you say makes sense to include.

Comment: I'd argue if you're pushing for Australia, then Canada would be in the list. Canada has the 3rd largest oil reserves, 3rd largest uranium reserves, plus many mined resources like gold, coal, platinum. Canada actually builds and exports nuclear reactors, something banned in Australia. Canada exports more food than Australia by value, and beats it in foods like wheat and corn. Canada can more easily trade with US, Mexico and Europe, and has the natural accessibility of human resources from the US.

Answer (score 3):

This question is highly opinion based. However, we can try to make an argument for and against every option.

1. USA

   - Why yes: Big diversified economy, technological leadership, strongest army, stable political system;
   - Why not: Looming [entitlement crisis](https://www.heritage.org/report/solutions-america-the-entitlement-crisis), political infighting;
2. China

   - Why yes: Big diversified economy, technologically advanced, strong political system, untapped potential;
   - Why not: Economy might have reached its peak, aging population;
3. EU

   - Why yes: Big diversified economy, technologically advanced, educated population;
   - Why not: Unevenly matched members, economically and politically, aging population, high entitlement spending;
4. Japan

   - Why yes: Sizeable diversified economy, technologically advanced, educated population;
   - Why not: Endless recession, aging population;
5. Russia

   - Why yes: Abundant mineral resources, technologically advanced, strong army;
   - Why not: Non-diversified economy, aging population;
6. India

   - Why yes: Sizeable diversified economy, lot of untapped potential;
   - Why not: Political system may not be stable enough to produce stable growth;
7. Brazil

   - Why yes: Abundant mineral resources;
   - Why not: Political system weakness;
8. Nigeria

   - Why yes: Abundant mineral resources, lot of untapped potential, potential leader in Africa;
   - Why not: Political system weakness coupled with security issues, low level of education;
9. Technological singularity

   - Why yes: Powers superior to tradition "superpowers";
   - Why not: 2050 may be still too early for it.

Comment: Speaking about the future is always be slightly or more opinion-based, but I try to make the game's lore more authentic than pure fiction. I say special thanks for the political system traits.